# How can I quickly create aliases with absolute paths?

Tags: path, alias, absolute-path

I often make mistakes in making aliases:

```
ln -S $Personal/Books $Buy/Books      (1)
```

Instead, I have to write the whole path to get the last command working:

```
ln -S /Users/user/something/.../Books /Users/user/something/.../Books     (2)
```

I would really love to get something similar to (1) working. It is so time consuming to do (2). How can I quickly create absolute paths for aliases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume in your example the paths *Personal* and *Buy* are both directories in your home directory. Then you can create a relative symlink by typing

```
cd Buy
ln -s ../Personal/Books Books
```

Comment: You should still do the same thing, provide ln a relative path